# Where can I ask Adobe Photoshop related questions on SO family?

Tags: discussion, support, stack-exchange

There is no [SE proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/), [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/photoshop/stats) is not the right place and [SU](https://superuser.com/tags/adobe-photoshop/stats) does not have any activity on Photoshop questions.

[image]

Where should I ask "need help doing this" type questions on SO family?

Comment: What are you talking about? You screenshotted yourself in the last week there were 4 question on Photoshop. That sounds like enough activity to me to ask a question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They should fit perfectly on Super User, but otherwise:

What about the SE site **[Photography and Photographic editing](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/1265/photography-and-photographic-editing)**?

Comment: How did I miss Photographic editing part? The url is http://photo.stackexchange.com/ and I always thought it to be just photography site.